# sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer() handles single column name in an array incorrectly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In a ColumnTransformer I want to use a Tfidf pipeline. But even for this simple example the type of the transform output of the original pipeline and the one in put into the ColumnTransformer is of very different type. Why is the type different?

Multiple columns can be passed as array ['col1', 'col2']. Why is is this not working for a single column ['col1']?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

X = pd.DataFrame({'message': ['Lets start.', 'This is it.', 'We are done.']})

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    clean_tokens = []
    for tok in tokens:
        clean_tok = lemmatizer.lemmatize(tok).lower().strip()
        clean_tokens.append(clean_tok)

    return clean_tokens

p = Pipeline(steps = [ 
            ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())
            ])  

print(p.fit_transform(X['message']))

#  (0, 6)        0.652490884512534
#  (0, 5)        0.652490884512534
#  (0, 0)        0.3853716274664007
#  (1, 7)        0.546454011634009
#  (1, 4)        0.546454011634009
#  (1, 3)        0.546454011634009
#  (1, 0)        0.3227445421804912
#  (2, 8)        0.546454011634009
#  (2, 2)        0.546454011634009
#  (2, 1)        0.546454011634009
#  (2, 0)        0.3227445421804912


ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [ 
        ('txt', p, ['message'])
    ])  

print(ct.fit_transform(X))

#array([[1.]])

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [ 
        ('txt', p, 'message')
    ])  

print(ct.fit_transform(X))

#[[0.38537163 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.65249088
#  0.65249088 0.         0.        ]
# [0.32274454 0.         0.         0.54645401 0.54645401 0.
#  0.         0.54645401 0.        ]
# [0.32274454 0.54645401 0.54645401 0.         0.         0.
#  0.         0.         0.54645401]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section 6.1.4 in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#make-column-transformer).

As per the documentation, whenever the transformer expects a 1D array as input, the columns were specified as a string ('title'). For the transformers which expects 2D data, we need to specify the column as a list of strings (['title']).